# mongoDB isMaster command too slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

In the mongodb logs I found isMaster command is taking too long (5 secs). This has started today morning, in earlier logs I couldn't see such a behavior. Also, I have seen over 170k such instances in today's log.

has any one seen this before? what could be the reason for this slowness.

```
2021-09-03T00:15:25.031-0400 I  COMMAND  [conn32] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1630642509, 884), signature: { hash: BinData(0, E2FBF02AE3EA7D8A6C9863DAAE621E9FCEA528B5), keyId: 6942951450167214081 } } } numYields:0 reslen:845 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 5008ms
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with DNS server and the hostname resolution was taking long and having some failures, which caused this weird issue.

It's resolved on MongoDB side after fixing DNS issue.